# Can I perform Linq OrderBy with asynchronous calls in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, asynchronous

I have an order by linq query, something like this like this:

```
var sortedList = unsortedList
                    .OrderBy(foo => foo.GetCurrentValue())
```

However, the method GetCurrentValue responds slowly (because it involves network communication and has considerable latency). As far as I observe, the code aboves call the method sequentally (a call has to finish before the next one is called, so if the list is long the sorting will be really slow.

Is there a way to tell linq to do it in parallel? i.e. evaluate the expression asynchronously and then compare the result after everyone is finished?

If not, any idea how to make our own implementation cleanly and easily?

Comment: A call to `OrderBy` on a PLINQ `(AsParallel)` query will automatically treat the query as `AsOrdered` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx I'm not sure what impact that would have on performance though, the MSDN article isn't clear on that.

Comment: @Snixtor that's a very helpful link, and probably it will solve my problem (testing now)! Why not post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN has an article specifically on "Order Preservation" in PLINQ - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677.aspx (per my earlier comment). An example given by the link:

```
var cityQuery = (from city in cities.AsParallel()
                 where city.Population > 10000
                 select city);
```

And just throwing it out there as a possible implementation, something like this? Where `slowList` is an enumerable collection of your "slow" objects. The `Parallel.ForEach` could be substituted with any other async "staging" operation for gathering the slow values.

```
    var stage1List = new List<dynamic>();
    var parOpt = new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30 };

    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(slowList, parOpt, slowObj =>
    {
        stage1List.Add(new { Obj = slowObj, Value = slowObj.GetSlowValue() });
    });

    var stage2List = stage1List.OrderBy(p => p.Value).Select(p => p.Obj);
```

Comment: why is there a need for such implementation when `unsortedList.AsParallel().OrderBy(foo => foo.GetSlowValue())` seems to work?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to specify the level of parallelism on an `AsParallel`? This said, a `Parallel.ForEach`, despite allowing the specification of a MaxDegreeOfParallelism won't necessarily parallelise it to that fullest extent. My line of thinking is that the `GetSlowValue()` call may be slow for reasons other than local processing power limits, so executing the method on 30 items at once may produce better performance? In essence, it's the usual issue of parallelism - How much?

Comment: The slowness is due to network latency, not processing power, so it does get faster if I parallelize them. In theory, I think more parallelism means better performance always.
 
Any idea what level of parallelism do they use if I just specify AsParallel?